# Generation of a Hamming Series

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, hamming-code

I have been trying to solve a programming problem, one of the modules of which requires me to generate Hamming sequences. The function takes input two numbers first a binary number N and another a decimal number K. It should now generate all possible numbers having a Hamming distance of up to K from N.

It would be really helpful if you provide me with an algorithm about how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algorithm is pretty simple. You just need to chose all possible binary numbers contains from 0 to K ones. And then xor it with N, just like this:

```
    public static Char[] Xor(Char[] a, Char[] b)
    {
        Char[] c = new Char[a.Length];
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < a.Length; ++i)
            if (a[i] == b[i])
                c[i] = '0';
            else
                c[i] = '1';

        return c;
    }

    public static void Generate(Char[] original, Char[] current, int position, int k)
    {
        if (position == original.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Xor(original, current));
            return;
        }

        if (k > 0)
        {
            current[position] = '1';
            Generate(original, current, position + 1, k - 1);
        }

        current[position] = '0';
        Generate(original, current, position + 1, k);
    }

    // Find all Number with hamming distance up to 2 from 01100
    Generate("01100".ToCharArray(), "00000".ToCharArray(), 0, 2);
```

Note: count of numbers that have Hamming distance up to K from N can be extremely big, as soon it exponentially grows depend on value of K.

Comment: Why char arrays? This whole problem just screams *bitmanipulation*

Comment: The only reason is code simplicity. Of course, bitmanipulation it's what you need there if you want qualitative solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate all number with K bits set by starting at `(1<<K)-1` and applying [NextPermutation](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation) until you've had them all.
XOR all those numbers with N.

Comment: A very interesting answer, may I know how the NextPermutation algorithm works. I tried it out but I am clueless about its input and outputs let alone its functioning. Can you please explain some of it ?

Comment: @Warangalite to be honest I don't actually *understand* it. I don't know why it works. It's just a function that takes a "string of bits" (as an int of course) and turns it into the lexicographically next string (int). So if you start at 00001111 and you keep applying it, it will run though all bytes that have 4 bits set, in lexicographical order (it takes an int so it will try to run further, just stop at 11110000). The order doesn't even matter in this case, it's just a way to directly generate all numbers with k bits set.

Comment: Thanks, though I liked the performance with this, I preferred the Java (though its not accurate) solution given above. Still thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach (since you didn't mention something about performance) is to iterate through 1 to p and bitwise xor it with N if the number has less than K bits set as 1. p has the same bit length as N.

Pseudo code:

```
for i in [0..p]
   if countBits(i) <= K then
      result.add(p xor N)
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this for Interview Street?  They ask you not to get others to do the problems for you.