# What is a quick way to get the n'th integer > 0, that has at most k bits set?

Tags: c#, math, bit

I have a series, values greater than 0, where the number of bits set is no more that `k`.

```
for instance, for `k = 2`

n    binary    value    bits_set
0    0000      0        0
1    0001      1        1
2    0010      2        1
3    0011      3        2
4    0100      4        1
5    0101      5        2
6    0110      6        2
7    1000      8        1
8    1001      9        2
9    1010      10       2
10   1100      14       2
... etc ...
```

Is there a computationally efficient way to find the `n`'th item in the series for a given value of `k`?

All my attempts have had very slow performance and I don't know how to tackle the problem efficiently.

Comment: "Nth number" means what? There are many numbers with at most M bits set. You are looking for the smallest one?

Comment: I mean the indexer operator eg array[n].

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information

Comment: Specify the conditions for the number. As I said, there are many numbers that satisfy the condition. Are you sorting them? What does the array have to do with anything?

Comment: No, it need to have at most M bits set.

Comment: @Jodrell `2^n + 1` has two bits set.

Comment: Say I need to find the 9th thing that has at most 2 bits set, it would be 0000, 0001, 0010, 0011, 00100, 00101, 00110, 01000, 01001. 01001

Comment: @trinalbadger587 put it in the question, or, ask another one that is fully written.

Comment: @Jodrell, do you think my question is understandable now?

Comment: @trinalbadger587, I understand, I edited your question to make it more understandable, if you ask it fresh like that you may get better results.

Comment: this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093493/generation-of-a-hamming-series

Comment: and this, https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Comment: @MBo That's not quite a duplicate.  That would give the number with exactly k bits set, not at most.  That also doesn't have an answer if k is too big.

Comment: @Teepeemm Yes, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the question is tagged C#, apologies for giving an answer in Python:

First, we shall find a way of counting how many distinct numbers there are with a certain number of bit out of an available space.  Then we shall find a way of ordering those results.

Denote f(b, s) as the number of ways of constructing a number with exactly s bits out of b set.

There is a recurrence relation here.  A number satisfying f(b, s) is either a number satisfying f(b-1, s) with a 0 on the front, or a number satisfying f(b-1, s-1) with a 1 on the front.  Therefore f(b, s) = f(b-1, s) + f(b-1, s-1).

Some base cases fill in that table:
f(b,0) is 1
f(b,s) is 1 where b = s

```
    10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
24   . . . . . . . . . . 1
23   . . . . . . . . . . 1
22   . . . . . . . . . . 1
21   . . . . . . . . . . 1
20   . . . . . . . . . . 1
19   . . . . . . . . . . 1
18   . . . . . . . . . . 1
17   . . . . . . . . . . 1
16   . . . . . . . . . . 1
15   . . . . . . . . . . 1
14   . . . . . . . . . . 1
13   . . . . . . . . . . 1
12   . . . . . . . . . . 1
11   . . . . . . . . . . 1
10   1 . . . . . . . . . 1
 9   0 1 . . . . . . . . 1
 8   0 0 1 . . . . . . . 1
 7   0 0 0 1 . . . . . . 1
 6   0 0 0 0 1 . . . . . 1
 5   0 0 0 0 0 1 . . . . 1
 4   0 0 0 0 0 0 1 . . . 1
 3   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 . . 1
 2   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 . 1
 1   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

It'll be useful to also build the table g(b, s) which denotes how many b-bit numbers have s or fewer bits set. g(b, s) = sum(i = 0 to s) f(b, i)

So we can now answer the question of how many numbers there are with exactly 10 bits set out of 24, that's f(24, 10) = 1961256, and we can answer how many numbers there are with at most 10 bits set out of 24, that's f(24, 10) + f(24, 9) + f(24, 8) ... + f(24, 1) + f(24, 0) = g(24, 10) = 4540386

But, if the question is to find the nth number such that at most 10 out of 24 bits are set, we need to be able to search this space in an ordered fashion.

First of all, note that any number with its first 1 in the nth bit is larger than any number with its first 1 in any bit later than n.

This means we can find the position of each number with just a single bit set followed by z zeros.  That is necessarily larger than g(z, max(z,10)).  We can slip an optimization in here and state that as all numbers in a 10-bit space are eligible (they can't possibly have more than 10 bits set) then the nth such number = n for all n <= 2^10.

If n > 2^10 (=> z > 10) we can search to find the location of the first set bit by finding the greatest z_10 such that g(z_10, 10) <= n.  If it actually equals n, we have found our answer so can stop.  If we want to be hyper efficient this can be even be done by binary search!

Otherwise, we must find the greatest z_9 such that g(z_9, 9) <= n - g(z_10, 10), then the greatest z_8 such that g(z_8, 8) <= n - g(z_10, 10) - g(z_9, 9) and so on until we hit our equality and have answered the question.

In Python:

```
class Memoize:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
        self.memo = {}
    def __call__(self, *args):
        if not args in self.memo:
            self.memo[args] = self.f(*args)
        return self.memo[args]

def g(b, s):
    r = 0
    for i in range(0, s+1):
        r = r + f(b, i)
    return r

def f(b,s):
    if b == s:
        return 1
    if s == 0:
        return 1
    if b < s:
        return 0
    return f(b-1, s) + f(b-1, s-1)

def build(s, n, i):
    d = (24 - len(s))
    if n <= 2 ** i:
        return s + format(n, '0%db' % (d))
    for z in range(i, d+1):
        x = g(z, i)
        if x < n:
            continue
        if x == n:
            return s + format(2 ** z, '0%db' % (d))
        y = g(z-1, i)
        return build(s + format(1, '0%db' % (d-(z-1))),
                     n - y,
                     i - 1)

def solve(n):
    return build("", n-1, 10)

f = Memoize(f)
g = Memoize(g)

for n in range(1, 4540387):
    print("%07d: %s" % (n, solve(n)))
```

Comment: I can't really read the python, could you give me a simple way of just answering my problem with the code please.